# Do we say "he has gaps between his teeth" or "he is gap-toothed" in everyday conversation?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

[image: young boy with a noticeable tooth-gapped smile]

My son's teeth are similar to the above picture. There are gaps between each pair of adjacent teeth.

Do we say "**he has gaps between his teeth**" or "**he is gap-toothed**" in everyday conversation?

Comment: You can use both, but _gap-toothed_ can also describe a person who has a front tooth missing.

Answer (score 1):

**gap-toothed** is the correct informal term for this: the technical term for a gap between teeth is a **diastema**.

I was going to say that the condition is relatively uncommon in the UK, so it is not something that comes up in everyday conversation. As a child, I had too many teeth, and had to have eight extracted. I checked with NGram, and this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gap%20toothed&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgap%20toothed%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgap%20toothed%3B%2Cc0) shows that the term gap-toothed has staged a rapid rise in usage since 1990.

Comment: You have to use "gap-toothed" carefully.  At least in the US it is used as an insult (especially in the form "gap-toothed yokel"), implying that the person is from an impoverished and uneducated rural area where dental care is unavailable, resulting in missing teeth.